# Java reactor flux not mapping according expectation

Tags: java, spring-boot, project-reactor

I have the following setup for a demo application:

- mongodb containing 2 collections: 1 with cryptocurrencies and 1 with the exchange rates of these cryptocurrencies
- spring webflux project to fetch realtime updates to these exchange rates using Server Sent events

I have a service which returns a `Flux` of `List<CryptoCurrencyRateDTO>` based on the currencies present in the cryptocurrency collection. I generate a random exchange rate for each of these currencies and stream them to the web client.

The service is this:

```
@Service
public class CryptoCurrencyRateService {
  @Autowired private CryptoCurrencyRateRepository rateRepository;
  @Autowired private CryptoCurrencyRepository currencyRepository;

  // constructor

  public Flux<List<CryptoCurrencyRateDTO>> realtimeRates() {
    return currencyRepository.findAll()
      .map(CryptoCurrency::getSymbol)
      .flatMap(rateRepository::findTopBySymbolOrderByTimestamp)
      .zipWith(
        Flux.<Long>generate(sink -> sink.next(Instant.now().toEpochMilli())),
        (rate, timestamp) -> new CryptoCurrencyRate(rate.getSymbol(), timestamp, randomRateBasedOnPrevious )
      )
      .flatMap(rateRepository::save)
      .map(rateMapper::toDto)
      .collectList()
      .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
      .repeat();
  }
}
```

The `CryptoCurrencyRateRepository` is as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface CryptoCurrencyRateRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<CryptoCurrencyRate, String> {
    Mono<CryptoCurrencyRate> findTopBySymbolOrderByTimestamp(String symbol);
}
```

However after the call to `.flatMap(rateRepository::findTopBySymbolOrderByTimestamp)` I only get a `Flux` containing 1 item while I thought I would get a `Flux` containing the top rate for each symbol from the `currencyRepository.findAll().map(CryptoCurrency::getSymbol)` call because my cryptocurrency collection contains 3 currencies.

When I look in the logging I see that the call to `findTopBySymbolOrderByTimestamp` is executed 3 times

```
2018-11-16 16:04:33.626 DEBUG 3387 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-3] o.s.d.m.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate       : find using query: { "symbol" : "BTC" } fields: Document{{}} for class: class nl.reactive.charts.server.domain.CryptoCurrencyRate in collection: cryptoCurrencyRate
2018-11-16 16:04:33.627 DEBUG 3387 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-3] o.s.d.m.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate       : find using query: { "symbol" : "ETH" } fields: Document{{}} for class: class nl.reactive.charts.server.domain.CryptoCurrencyRate in collection: cryptoCurrencyRate
2018-11-16 16:04:33.629 DEBUG 3387 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-3] o.s.d.m.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate       : find using query: { "symbol" : "XRP" } fields: Document{{}} for class: class nl.reactive.charts.server.domain.CryptoCurrencyRate in collection: cryptoCurrencyRate
```

Comment: "`findTopBySymbolOrderByTimestamp` is executed 3 times"   ...due to `CryptoCurrency::getSymbol` (return 3 entries!?) ...and that `xxxTopxxx` query finds only *one* result is also "as designed" ...right? Please consider to accept your(any) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that my expectations were correct. The only thing that was going wrong was that not all objects got saved in Mongo because they were missing an ID.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce your issue. This is how I mimic it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flux<String> stringFlux = Flux.fromStream(Stream.of("a", "b", "c"));
    System.out.println(realtimeRates(stringFlux).blockFirst());
}

static Flux<List<String>> realtimeRates(Flux<String> list) {
    Flux<String> symbols = list.map(Scratch::getSymbol);
    Flux<String> topRates = symbols.flatMap(Scratch::findTopBySymbolOrderByTimestamp);
    Flux<String> zip = topRates.zipWith(
        Flux.<Long>generate(sink -> sink.next(Instant.now().toEpochMilli())),
        (rate, timestamp) -> rate + timestamp.toString());
    Mono<List<String>> listMono = zip.collectList();
    Mono<List<String>> delayElement = listMono.delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    Flux<List<String>> repeat = delayElement.repeat();
    return repeat;
}

static Mono<String> findTopBySymbolOrderByTimestamp(String symbol) {
    return Mono.just("other-" + symbol);
}

static String getSymbol(String rate) {
    return rate.toLowerCase();
}
```

As you can see, you will get something like `[other-a1542821666133, other-b1542821666133, other-c1542821666133]`.

How are you checking the flatmap result? be aware that if you do it with a `blockFirst()` or `blockLast()` methods you will get only one element since its a `Flux<String>` (check the `topRates` variable in the code above)

Comment: I'm doing nothing with `blockFirst` or `blockLatest`. Your example works indeed and it works like I expected it to work. For some reason in my case (with the reactive repository) it only takes one of the `topRates` instead of all